# De filas a columnas en mariadb

Tags: mariadb, pivot

Buen día. Necesito consultar un total de registros, el cual los agrupo por áreas de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT AREA, COUNT(*) AS numeroTareasArea FROM sio_gestion_tareas_2 GROUP BY AREA
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito que los áreas pasen a ser columnas con su total de tareas, teniendo en cuenta que las áreas pueden aumentar o disminuir (datos dinámicos) una vez se vayan ingresando o quitando tareas.

Según consulte se haría por medio de una tabla pivot o también si se podría hacer mediante subconsultas, pero teniendo en cuenta que las áreas pueden aumentar o disminuir.

Motor db : mariadb

Versión: 10.2.39

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Desde tempranas versiones de MariaDB (creo recordar 10.0.2 Alpha) existe el *storage engine* CONNECT con el Tipo Tabla: PIVOT (Table Type: PIVOT) (ver documentación: [CONNECT PIVOT Table Type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-pivot-table-type/). Lo siento pero toda la documentación está en Inglés). Dicho Tipo Tabla puede ayudar, sin embargo, su requisito de datos dinámicos posiblemente sea una limitante para usarlo ampliamente.

Un artículo interesante (en Inglés) puede ser encontrado en: [Pivoting in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pivoting-in-mariadb/).

Inspirado en el artículo comentado anteriormente, en una versión muy reducida mucho menos genérica y adaptada al caso de uso específico presentado en la pregunta, aquí una opción que puede evaluar:

```sql
WITH `dynamic_columns_AREA` AS (
  SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'COUNT(CASE WHEN `AREA` = ''', `AREA`, ''' THEN 1 END) ',
          CONCAT('`', `AREA`, '`')
        )
    ) `dynamic_columns`,
    COUNT(*) `count`
  FROM
    `sio_gestion_tareas_2`
)
SELECT
  IF(
    `dynamic_columns_AREA`.`count` > 0,
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT ',
      `dynamic_columns_AREA`.`dynamic_columns`,
      ' FROM `sio_gestion_tareas_2`;'
    ),
    'DO (SELECT NULL);'
  ) INTO @`sql`
FROM
  `dynamic_columns_AREA`;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @`sql`;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4700031e9235cba20cdb8e79f02483d4).

**Nota**: No olvide la variable de sistema de servidor: [group_concat_max_len](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#group_concat_max_len) al usar la función [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/).